# How to display regex as plain text instead of resolving it PHP

Tags: php, regex

Lets say I have preg_replace like this:

```
preg_replace("/\{{2}([a-z]+\|*.*)\}{2}/Ue", 'Im here', $Input);
```

It will replace e.g. {{youtube}} with "Im here" or {{youtube|id=something}} which works great. However what if I wanted to display it without replacing it? I would essentially want something like:

```
\{{youtube}}
```

which would not get resolved. Is it possible somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should learn to search up the manual. Just use [`preg_match_all()`](http://php.net/preg_match_all). Also please do not ever use the `e` modifier. It stands for `eval` which is deprecated and dangerous. You should be using [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback) if you want to apply some logic while replacing. As for the expression you're using, it can be improved although some of these are just my preference:

- `\{{2}` : it would be shorter to use `\{\{` although I would just go for `{{` since PCRE is smart enough to know it's not about a quantifier. The same goes for the closing tag.
- `([a-z]+\|*.*)` : I don't see why you don't just use `.*` ? If you want it to start with letters, then I think you also should include uppercase letters.
- `U` : I think this modifier is a pain and makes the regex hard to understand. So when someone reads the expression, s?he has always to keep in mind that there is a reluctant modifier. I would remove this modifier and explicitly write down `.*?` instead of `.*` with `U`.
- `e` : Like I said this one is dangerous and should not be used.

In the end, I think it might be better to use `{{.*?}}` or `{{[a-zA-Z].*?}}` if you want it to start with a letter or `{{([a-zA-Z].*?)}}` if you want to capture the value in between `{{}}`. Note that this expression doesn't match nested tags. Here's a simple php sample:

```
$input = 'this is a test {{youtube}} also this {{youtube|id=something}} is something special.';
preg_match_all('~{{([a-zA-Z].*?)}}~', $input, $m);
print_r($m);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => {{youtube}}
            [1] => {{youtube|id=something}}
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => youtube
            [1] => youtube|id=something
        )

)
```

Note that I used `~` as delimiter instead of `/` so that I won't need to escape `/` in my expression(s).

<kbd>[**Play**](http://regex101.com/r/eQ6bW7)</kbd> <sup><sup>Click here to play</sup></sup>

Comment: Thank you very much, I will go through all suggestion and fix the eval(). Im indeed using some logic afterwards, I hope it will work equally good with the callback you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) and list your matches without replacing them.

Comment: You might have answered it before I get a chance to edit it, however do you mind sharing some example even in pseudo code as Im quite lost in here.